# Strange symbol name in output of nm command

Tags: c, linux, linker, nm

I built a dynamic lib called InterfaceLayer.so.
When I call:

```
> nm InterfaceLayer
```

As output, I get some symbols that look like:

```
00000e28  T _Z5startv
```

while I was expecting it to be "**start**", just as the name of the function I defined in the code.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's because of C++ name mangling

```
nm -C
```

demangles them.

To prevent name mangling,

- use a C compiler (gcc, not g++), name your source file .c (not .cpp)
- or declare extern "C":

.

my.h

```
  extern "C" 
  {
        void start();
        void finish();
  }
```

This will give them "C" linkage, meaning they can't be overloaded, cannot pass by reference, nothing c++ :)

Comment: `extern "C"` does not mean that functions cannot pass by reference.

Comment: Suggestion to switch from C++ to C "to prevent name mangling" sounds like a suggestion to use guillotine to prevent dandruff. BTW, the OP never stated that they wanted to prevent it.

Comment: Agreed. Explaining that C++ is the source of the mangling still might add perspective. "Why does this happen" was explicitly in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like [C++ name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Handling_of_C_symbols_when_linking_from_C.2B.2B).

Comment: I often use *c++filt* when I need to demangle them: `c++filt _Z5startv`

Comment: nm myApp | c++filt; # Is exactly what I needed. I'm on OSX and XCode with it's warped GNU tool stack, and it doesn't support nm -C. Thanks @karlphillip

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have mentioned, this is likely becuase of C++ name mangling.  If you want the symbol to be accessible by it's 'unmangled' name, and it's implemented in C++, you'll need to us `extern "C"` to tell the C++ compiler that it has a C linkage.

In the header that has the function prototype, you'll want something like:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

// the prototype for start()...


#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

This will ensure that if the function is used by a C++ compiler, it'll get the `extern "C"` on the declaration, and that if it's used by a C module, it won't be confused by the `extern "C"` specifier.

You implementation in the .cpp file doesn't need that stuff if you include the header before the function definition. It'll use the linkage specification it saw from the previous declaration.  However, I prefer to still decorate the function definition with `extern "C"` just to ensure that everything is in sync (note that in the .cpp file you don't need the `#ifdef` preprocessing stuff - it'll always be compiled as C++.